# Monge-Ampere equation

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, ordinary-differential-equations

I'm considering the Monge-Ampere equation in $\mathbb{R}^n$:

$\mathrm{det}(D_{ij}u)=f$.

I know that its linearized coefficient matrix is $\mathrm{cof}(D_{ij}u)$, i.e. the co-factor matrix of the Hessian.  What are the eigenvalues of this matrix?